# Compile app in React Native - Android and IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a question with React native. If I develop in the Windows environment, how do I pass this code on the Mac to distribute the project to Android and IOS? or can I compile IOS on windows?

Comment: you can compile IOS on windows by using EXPO